# Earth Engine authentication issue: "Request had invalid authentication credentials"

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to load one surface reflectance image from Sentinel-2 MSI Level-2A in Google Earth Engine, but I get the following error:

> ImageCollection (Error)
>   Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Here is my code and the roi:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point(-94.86,36.93);
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2017-05-01', '2017-06-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first();
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min:0, max: 0.2}, 'True colour image');
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: I assume you run this code in your own web app and not in the ee sandbox. In the error message it kinda tells you what's wrong. your authentication isn't set up correctly. Furthermore, S2_SR isn't available in Earth Engine in 2017 on that specific location. First available would be 2018-12-13.

Comment: Thank you @g07kore for your response. However, I have another question, do you have any suggestions on how to fix/set up correctly my authentication?

Comment: This question is probably better directed at the [Earth Engine Developers discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers)